# Extracting alt text from image links with a JavaScript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, regex, perl, alt

I found a way to extract alt text from image links through a Perl script I found. However, the method entails downloading the target HTML; processing it through the Perl script, which then produces a text file with the specific alt text I need; and then removing some extra bits of text I couldn't filter out via code manually, as I don't know how to make regex work with Perl (I tried installing PCRE to no avail).

This method is still impractical, and I'm sure I can extract alt text through a JavaScript bookmarklet much, much faster, and get the output neatly listed in a new tab, instantly. However, I have no knowledge on how to convert the Perl script I have to JavaScript, nor how to write one from scratch.

Here's the Perl script:

```
{
    # Get data from HTML file
    my $From = cwd() . '/' . $ARGV[0];
    open( HTMLFILE, '<' . $From ) or die( "Cannot open $From to read." );

    my $Html;
    read HTMLFILE, $Html, -s $From;
    close HTMLFILE;

    # Find IMG elements
    print "Images found!";
    my %AltTexts;
    while ( $Html =~ /(<IMG\b.*?>)/isg ) {
        my $ImgElement = $1;

        # Find SRC tag
        $ImgElement =~ /SRC\s*=\s*([\"\'])(.*?)\1/is;
        my $Src = $2;

        # Find ALT tag & store text
        if ( $ImgElement =~ /ALT\s*=\s*([\"\'])(.*?)\1/is ) {
            $AltTexts{$Src} = $2;
        }
        else {    # No ALT found so give it default text if none already found
            unless ( exists( $AltTexts{$Src} ) ) {
                $AltTexts{$Src} = 'NO_ALT_TEXT';
            }
        }
    }

    # Write extracted data to a file
    my $To = cwd() . '/' . $ARGV[0] . '.txt';
    open( ALTTEXTFILE, '>' . $To ) or die( "Cannot open $To to write." );

    foreach my $SrcPath ( sort keys %AltTexts ) {
        print ALTTEXTFILE "$AltTexts{$SrcPath}\n";
    }
    close ALTTEXTFILE;
}
```

I did tweak it to stop the script from printing the link, removed blank lines, etc.

The original script can be found [here](http://duramecho.com/ComputerPrograms/HtmlImgAltTextExtractAndInsert/)

So, my question is what would the JavaScript for extracting alt text look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
javascript:(function() {
  var imgs = document.images,alts=[];
  for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
      alts.push(imgs[i].getAttribute("alt") || "no alt");
  }
  alert(alts.join("\n"));
})()
```

Example code:

```js
(function() {
  var imgs = document.images,alts=[];
  for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
    alts.push(imgs[i].getAttribute("alt") || "no alt");
  }
  console.log(alts);
})()
```

```html
<img alt="alt1" />
<img alt="" />
<img alt="alt2" />
```

To show in new window (popup blockers allowing)

```
javascript:(function() {
  var imgs = document.images,alts=[],w;
  for (var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) {
    alts.push(imgs[i].getAttribute("alt") || "no alt");
  }
  if (alts.length>0) {
    w = window.open("","_blank");
    if (w) {
      w.document.write(alts.join("<br />"));
      w.document.close();
    }
    else {
      alert("cannot pop\n"+alts.join("\n"));
    }
  }
})()
```

To avoid duplicates:

change

```
alts.push(imgs[i].getAttribute("alt") || "no alt");
```

to

```
var alt = imgs[i].getAttribute("alt");
if (alts && alts.indexOf(alt)==-1) alts.push(alt);
```

Comment: This is great. Any way to make the output show in a separate browser tab instead of a dialog box?

Comment: See update - not tested since the sandbox here does not allow it

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you, sir.

Comment: You are welcome. Just to let you know your question is actually off topic here as seen in the [help], but I like bookmarklets :)

Comment: As with perl, I couldn't avoid duplicate alt text from showing up with the results (for example, 's page in joey's page). Is there a way to remove an entire duplicate phrase from the output?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of upfront requirements and the offtopic. The update doesn't seem to work for me. I'm trying to ignore an exact, literal phrase - " 's page", which still keeps showing after each result.

Comment: Email me the page in question, please